# C program stops after first the first recursive call

Tags: c

I've tried to use character data type to compare in variable `reply` if equal to `y` it will continue calling the function `recursion()`, however, it did only 1 `recursion()` call and the program terminated. This only work if I use the int data type, as the variable to compare. Please anyone can let me know why this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recursion()
{
    char reply;
    printf("Continue?:");
    reply=getchar();
    if(reply=='y')
    {
        printf("Continued\n");
        recursion();
    }
}

int main()
{
    recursion();
    return(0);
}
```

output:

```
Laptop1:User1$ ./recur 
Continue?:y
Continued
Continue?:Laptop1:User1$
```

Comment: Check which type `getchar` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when end-users enter `'y'` in the terminal, they press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This inserts another character into the stream - `'\n'`. That is the character that the next call to `getchar()` would return, ending the chain of calls due to

```
if(reply=='y')
```

condition evaluating to "false".

You can fix the problem in several ways - for example, by using `scanf`:

```
if (scanf(" %c", &reply) == 1 && reply == 'y')
//         ^
// Note the space above
```

Adding a space character in front of `%c` ensures that `scanf` skips whitespace characters before reading the character into `reply` variable.

Answer (score 3):

`getchar()` will read newline character if it is, and it will prevent it from continueing.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getchar2()
{
    int c;
    do
    {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c == '\n'); /* ignore newline characters */
    return c;
}

void recursion()
{
    int reply;
    printf("Continue?:");
    reply=getchar2();
    if(reply=='y')
    {
        printf("Continued\n");
        recursion();
    }
}

int main()
{
    recursion();
    return(0);
}
```